# Can't access router webpage wirelessly or wired

Tags: networking, router, bridge, hotspot, fios

I am having some difficulties reaching the router webpage to edit the settings of the router. At this time the router I am trying to access is just acting as another hotspot (Bridge?) off my main Verizon Fios Gateway router. I set this up because my Verizon Fios router would not reach the bedrooms on the other side of the house so I took an older NetGear router and connected it via ethernet through a powerline adapter.

Now that everything has been set up for a few months I can't seem to gain access to the Netgear router settings web page. I have tried accessing it via the "routerlogin.net" address which is on the back of the router, by typing in the IP address for the router in my chrome address bar. Either way it will only bring me to the router settings page for the Verizon Fios Gateway router. If I disconnect from the network and turn off the Fios Gateway and try to connect via an ethernet cable from the Netgear to my laptop and try to access the webpage it will not connect and says there is no internet connection.

Everything on the network is currently working except I cannot get an internet connection on my Android phone when connected to the Netgear. I am trying to remedy this situation but not being able to get to the router's settings is kind of setting me back.

Comment: This has been already answered [here](http://superuser.com/questions/859490/how-do-i-access-my-modems-gui-when-its-in-bridged-mode).

Comment: So that link is telling me just to reset the Netgear router, I would prefer not to do this since it took me a while to get the Netgear setup correctly where everything was getting a connection. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you my case: I have a router configured as an AP on bridge-mode-only at home. When looking at the IPs leased by my DHCP server I can see an IP assigned to the this router/AP and so I can reach it to configure it. Your options are to either look at the IPs leased by your DHCP server or to scan your network in search of an IP with an open port 80.